# Hiding long table-cell content in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have an HTML table that has some cells with very large amounts of content  (e.g. 1KB).    Most of the cells have much less than this, 15 bytes or so.

I want to hide the large content in a tooltip.   What's the best way to do this?   E.g. show the first 15 bytes or so with a "..." then let a user hover or click to see the rest (or alternately,  not even show the first 15 bytes if that's not easy)

We're using Bootstrap if that makes any difference.

Comment: Put everything aftert the 1st 15 characters into a span and change it's css `display:` property from `none` to `inline` and back on hover/click. Note that hover may have unintended side-effects if the content is in-line and the page is scrolled.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good strategy......what are the magic words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple possible implementation is ... ([Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/YG7bK/))

```
<div
    onmouseover="document.getElementById('Overflow1').style.display='inline'"
    onmouseout="document.getElementById('Overflow1').style.display='none'">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     
    <span id="Overflow1" style="display: none">
        consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce a erat non nunc facilisis pulvinar. Ut dignissim ut nisi eu porttitor. Nulla cursus, dolor fringilla ullamcorper dictum, arcu orci faucibus sem, ullamcorper mattis odio sapien quis tortor. Proin dictum vel neque non malesuada. Pellentesque at consectetur augue. Curabitur ipsum est, posuere commodo feugiat quis, suscipit at neque.
    </span>
</div>
```

Of course for cleaner code, you should consider factoring out methods (or even better, adding [event handlers using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/))

Comment: You're very welcome - I do suggest you read up on the [jQuery hover event handler](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) It'll make it all so much easier and all you have to do is include jQuery in your page. Good luck